# Danish and Finnish Localization on the App Store

Tags: localization, app-store

We localized our app in Danish and Finnish, as well as description, screenshots, keywords and etc. BUT.
App Store still displays our app in English. Probably there exists some specific features when working with Danish and Finnish? All other languages are displayed correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: I think that the App Store language is being set by region too, not only the language.. Hope it helps

Comment: But we tried at least 15 other languages - all of them were correct except Danish and Finnish :(

Comment: You changed the device language and it changed too?

Comment: Try to change the region to Finland in the same place you set the device language and see if it helps

Comment: iTunes says that in these countries English is the primary language (and Finnish/Danisg go only after English). Why?

Comment: Maybe English is being used there more than Finnish and Danish? I haven't been there... I would trust apple with that decision... It's their App Store